# Model changed during database created

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-deployment

I have uploaded my MVC3 project , it's s simple blog , at first it works well but after couple hours! following error appears (I've made custom error to Off to see the error)

```
The model backing the 'SiteContext' context has changed since the database was created. Either manually delete/update the database, or call Database.SetInitializer with an IDatabaseInitializer instance. For example, the DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges strategy will automatically delete and recreate the database, and optionally seed it with new data.
```

to solve this I have to manually delete my database and create again and then restore to the backup that I have created. but after after 2 hours again I get the error!

I really don't have any idea , what caused that ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a model and ask EF to create a database from it, EF would **hash** the model and store the hash value with the database. Whenever the context is created, EF recomputes the hash and matches it against what is stored at the database. If the model changes in any way, the resulting hash will be different and EF will throw the exception you have just seen. This is done in order to keep the model in sync with the database.

Is there any way the model could have changed during runtime?

One thing you could do to figure out the difference is to

1.Re-create the database from the model as you are doing now and get it scripted (script1.sql).

2.Wait till the error happens and delete the db and re-create it again and script it (script2.sql)

3.Try to compare the two and see whether you can spot a difference in the schemas.

This should give you an idea of what has changed in the model.

Goodluck